# USB 3.0 port as 20v power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, cable, usb-3

I'm looking for a way to get the stated 20V 5A out of an USB 3.0 port to power an amplifier. Found power supplies but no easy USB 3.0 cable to DC power jack/connector (20V). Does it exist either or when it doesn't exist, what's the reason it doesn't exists?

Comment: Oh man, a downvote. What's wrong with you people, bad hairday? When downvoting, please provide me some info.

Comment: I read your question that seeks a hardware recomendation.  I didn't submit a comment because the close vote speaks for itself

Comment: You should look at the USB **Power Delivery** specifications, it is a distinct extension of the USB 3.0 specification, not all USB 3.0 hubs/power adapters support USB Power Deliver 3.0 specifications. See http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/USB_PD_R3_0_V1.0a_20160325.pdf for more information about how to get 20v/100w to work, there is more to it than just a physical connection (handshaking, protocol negotiation, etc)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the document, masive info wow. Found 20V@3A but requires some 'interfacing'. I understand why it doesn't exist because it is not just a power supply like USB 2. Sad.

Comment: By the way - are you thinking about getting this from a laptop? Most laptops' power supplies are not going to be able to source an extra 100 watts beyond what the unit is already using. Heck, a lot of them are rated for less than 100 watts total.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan: You are right but an laptop or usb (class-d) amp doesn't suck these ratings continuously, these are maximum ratings.

Comment: If you put a kill-a-watt or similar on a laptop's AC cord you will be surprised. Nor is there a large capacitor in the laptop, or its PSU, or the USB interface that can provide any significant surge capability. If the supply is good for 90 watts and the laptop is only using 50 and your power amp suddenly needs 50, you're asking for more than is there. The result could be erratic operation in the laptop, among other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm severely mistaken the USB 3.0 spec for 20V 5A is the maximum that the connector can handle. That's the connector, not the cable, supply side, or receive side. And it's the maximum, not the standard. Your standard USB 3.0 port will only supply a max of 5V, and current/wattage will be limited to whatever that particular "supplying" USB port is rated for. In addition, using usb for power supply to high powered devices is rare, because most USB ports don't have high wattage/current ratings. As such, you will probably not find a USB to DC connector that can handle that wattage/amperage.

On a side note, if you're using 20V at 5A, you need to know what you're doing, or you WILL end up frying something, possibly yourself. Please go over your project specifics with someone who knows electricity before you try doing anything DIY with more than 5V or 100mA.

Comment: You are correct. The 20V 5A rating is what the connector has to be able to handle before failure. But a USB port will actually only provide 5 volts at .1.8 A or less (that is for the "fast charging" mode of USB 3.0).

Comment: Ah, thanks, clear. What I want is not possible. One question: Is it possible to get the 1.8 amps without interfacing anyway? Read that a specific resistor value is needed between data lines? Any info on that?

Comment: @Erwinus - Outlined by the USB specification.  The resistor is used for identification purposes.  Hence the reason Benson Leung has reviewed hundreds of USB 3.1 Type C cables.

Comment: [Incorrect](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/PD_1.0_Introduction.pdf). Also, you are not going to "fry yourself" with 20V.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for 100 watts (20 volta at 5 amps). Even USB 3.1 can only supply 5 volts at 1.8 A, absolute maximum. That's 9 watts. It is flatly not possible to draw 100 watts from a source that can only supply 9. That's why the product you seek does not exist.

Comment: Do you guys even pretend to research things before you post? The USB Power Delivery spec indicates that Profile 5 is capable of delivering 100 W (20 volts @ 5A). Please see [this presentation](http://www.usb.org/developers/powerdelivery/PD_1.0_Introduction.pdf).

Comment: True, but the OP gave no indication that their USB 3.0 port offered compatibility with the PD spec. It's optional. The popular tech press has done a lousy job of describing this, leading people to believe that any USB 3.0 port can be expected to provide 100 watts.